# asp.net mvc issue related partail view script

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am Using Partial View in my complet Project with single view page.
I am adding my script inline in required partail. The problem is that when my partail is calling first time its works fine, but if I open next time then the events of my scripts any fires multiple time.
my script is in partailview page inside this page the child partail is calling for that this script.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $(document.body).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      $(":input,select,textarea")[$(":input,select,textarea").index(document.activeElement) + 1].focus();
      return false;                    
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

this is Index partail child partail is form partail.

When I call again Index Partail first clear the div which was Index partail html then append the Index partail using ajax.

Comment: If I got you right, you're adding event handler each time the partial view is rendered. Try naming your handler function `keyDownHandler` and moving it before `$(document.body).keydown`, so then you'll just call $(document.body).keydown(keyDownHandler). This should prevent from adding new listener each time. See "Multiple identical event listeners" at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial views shouldn't be used to render script, the idea behind partial views are they can be rendered *multiple* times on the same page....more often than not that isn't what you want with script.

The MVC way of doing this would be to declare a section in your `Layout.ascx` for scripts (generally just before `</body>`

```
@RenderSection("scripts", false)
</body>
```

Then in the top level view of the partial, include the script that you want to call from inside the partial

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document.body).keydown(function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    $(":input,select,textarea")[$(":input,select,textarea").index(document.activeElement) + 1].focus();
                    return false;                    
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

This will result in the script being rendered once with the page.

Comment: ..my Complet Project is single page project ...so all pages are partailview this code is not working .....i am having left menu from i open page called index paratail script inside that page..i open anothere partail inside that ....in which that script is required  ...when i come again to left menu and call page the script is fire muliple times...@section script is not working in partail view page..

Comment: @KiranKota it shouldn't matter whether it's a SPA or not, the rule is the same. You add this script to the *top level* page to make sure it's rendered only once and then your partial view should have access to it.

Comment: thanks for reply...................we cannot use script inside the partailview because my project so big i have al most completing state and i got this issue

Comment: @KiranKota sorry I am not sure I understand what you mean? I am not saying you put this script in a partial view, you put this script in the *page* itself (I keep repeating *top-level* page).

Comment: sorry my english not much good.......sorry for that..........script is inside the partailview in our case .................................but as u saying to put in top level page....our top level page is only one .....so it is very hard to include all scripts in one page is there any othere solution to do that............ @james ..

Comment: i got the solution using $(doucment) will truble while using script inside partailview which render muliple time rather then creating funtion in script will not genrate this issue..